# Why are the following lines (the golden and black one) parallel?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Screenshot of Pythagorea game]
So I was fooling around on Pythagorea and noticed that if I draw the grey line, the extension hits the top at a certain point. If I connect point A to that point, the golden and black lines are parallel. Is there a reason for this or is it merely a coincidence?

Comment: How is "the grey line" defined? That is, how are you choosing to place the endpoints?

Comment: It looks purely coincidental.  If you were to slightly adjust the black line it would change the slope slightly but the change would be otherwise imperceptible with the vertices and lines you've drawn making the lines no longer parallel.

Comment: You must tell us how the grey line is defined, because there is no special slope for it. You could chose any other, obtaining a different result.